# Android OnClickListener - identify a button

Tags: android, events, resources, listener

I have the activity:

```
public class Mtest extends Activity {
  Button b1;
  Button b2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
    b2.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
    ...
  }
  View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // MY QUESTION STARTS HERE!!!
      // IF b1 do this
      // IF b2 do this
      // MY QUESTION ENDS HERE!!!
    }
  }
}
```

How do I check which button has been clicked?

Comment: [Comparison of five different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729687/3681880) to add OnClickListeners for multiple buttons

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You will learn the way to do it, in an easy way, is:

```
public class Mtest extends Activity {
  Button b1;
  Button b2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
    b2.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);
    ...
  }
  View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // it was the 1st button
    }
  };
  View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // it was the 2nd button
    }
  };
}
```

Or, if you are working with just one clicklistener, you can do:

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
          // it was the first button
          break;
        case R.id.b2:
          // it was the second button
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Though, I don't recommend doing it that way since you will have to add an `if` for each button you use. That's hard to maintain.

Comment: Well, actually that's not correct. `View` is not a `Button`, but `Button` is a `View`. Though, you can cast a `View` to a `Button`. Keep in mind that the second way to do it is not recommended... maybe that v may not be a Button, which will generate a cast exception.

Comment: Actually both ways are not recommended, see my answer

Comment: Its actually quite simple to replace the if, elses with a single switch case statement that you switch on the id of the view and the cases are id's from R.java

Comment: Just wondering why you cast v to a Button anyway. getId() is defined for Views as well. Therefore I really wouldn't recommend the 2nd method but prefer Christian's solution!

Answer (score 76):

Or you can try the same but without listeners. On your button XML definition:

```
android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
```

And in your code define the method `ButtonOnClick`:

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button1:
        doSomething1();
        break;
      case R.id.button2:
        doSomething2();
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the other answers that use a bunch of event handlers, `if` statements, and listeners. Listeners are great if buttons are created at runtime, but that's often not the case.

Comment: While an interesting different approach, XML hooks for listeners are rough around the corners with `Fragment`s, as the callback must reside in the activity (not the fragment).

Comment: My prob is doSomething2() cant be reached without throwing either an InvocationTargetException or a NullPointerException (or both).

Comment: Just a sidenote: the statement "without listeners" here is wrong. You're only declaring the listener in XML, that's all.

Answer (score 41):

I prefer:

```
class MTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
            ....
            break;
        case R.id.b2:
            ....
            break;
    }   
}
```

`Switch`-`case` is easier to maintain than `if`-`else`, and this implementation doesn't require making many class variables.

Comment: This worked perfectly. You need to implement _OnClickListener-android.view.View_ and not _OnClickListener-android.content.DialogInterface_

Answer (score 16):

[Five Ways to Wire Up an Event Listener](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2359) is a great article overviewing the various ways to set up a single event listener. Let me expand that here for multiple listeners.

### 1. Member Class

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //attach an instance of HandleClick to the Button
        HandleClick handleClick = new HandleClick();
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(handleClick);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(handleClick);
    }    
    private class HandleClick implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Interface Type

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(handleClick);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(handleClick);
    }
    private OnClickListener handleClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

### 3. Anonymous Inner Class

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### 4. Implementation in Activity

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // do stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### 5. Attribute in View Layout for OnClick Events

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void HandleClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // do stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="HandleClick" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="HandleClick" />
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to save instances of the 2 button in the class code, follow this BETTER way (this is more clear and fast!!) :

```
public void buttonPress(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_one:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.button_two:
        // do something else
        break;
    case R.id.button_three:
        // i'm lazy, do nothing
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way of doing it is a single listener from activity , like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    .......  code

    //my listener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.mybutton) { 
            DoSomething();
            return;
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.mybutton2) { 
            DoSomething2();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I Like to do it with single IF instead of switch-else, but if you prefer that, then you should do:

```
//my listener
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.mybutton:
        { 
             DoSomething();
             break;
        }

        case R.id.mybutton2:
        {
            DoSomething();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way is by `switch`-ing between v.getId(). Having separate anonymous OnClickListener for each Button is taking up more memory. Casting View to Button is unnecessary. Using if-else when switch is possible is slower and harder to read. In Android's source you can often notice comparing the references by if-else:

```
if (b1 == v) {
 // ...
} else if (b2 == v) {
```

I don't know exactly why they chose this way, but it works too.

Comment: because it is no longer possible since v14 where ids are not treated not constant

Comment: @ognian I followed up to here because you said the main answer uses deprecated approaches. Nowadays with Android 5.0 Lollipop released, is your answer still true, or time made it become a falacy, like the comment above suggests? I really don't know what to think, or which direction to take from here.

Answer (score 7):

use setTag();

like this:

```
@Override    
public void onClick(View v) {     
    int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();     
    switch (tag) {     
    case 1:     
        System.out.println("button1 click");     
        break;     
    case 2:     
        System.out.println("button2 click");     
       break;   
    }     
}
```

Comment: I came here looking for a method to pass additional parameters to a handler, this is exactly what I wanted. The tag can be declared in Markup.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Cristian C's answer (sorry, I do not have the ability to make comments), if you make one handler for both buttons, you may directly compare v to b1 and b2, or if you want to compare by the ID, you do not need to cast v to Button (View has getId() method, too), and that way there is no worry of cast exception.

Comment: Another option would be to do a "if (v instanceof Button) { // Cast to Button and do stuff here }"

Answer (score 4):

```
Button mybutton = new Button(ViewPagerSample.this);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button 1 Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

[Check this article for more details](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=e1f43037-946b-4e71-9887-7354df4749dd)

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of some of the existing answers.