# How do I determine which button was pressed from a list of buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml file for a cardview to be used in a recyclerview in my main android class. This cardview contains a button that will be used to delete the cardview from the list. The problem I have encountered is that all of the buttons in the recyclerview have identical onClick values and I do not know how to differentiate between them.

Here is my button in the cardview xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:onClick="DeleteCard"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

In my main class, I have a function DeleteCard which runs whenever I press any of the delete buttons. I have a TextView in my cardview as well, and I was wondering if it was possible to somehow retrieve the text that is in the TextView when I press the delete button so I know which one to delete.

This is my onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(TimeViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    int min = (int)(times.get(i).time / (60 * 1000));
    int remaining = (int)(times.get(i).time % (60 * 1000));
    int sec = remaining / 1000;
    remaining = remaining % (1000);
    int mill = (remaining%1000)/10;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    personViewHolder.time.setText(min + ":" + df.format(sec) + "." + mill);
    personViewHolder.date.setText(times.get(i).date);
}
```

I want to get the text from date and use that as a parameter to remove that key in the SharedPreferences. Here is the method that runs when a delete button is pressed:

```
public void DeleteCard(View view){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = history.edit();
    editor.remove("Date Here");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Side note, better to use a contextual action bar for delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onclick on Button in onBindViewHolder not in xml and add a tag of position or unique identifier to this button. So when you will click then inside onclick extract tag from view object and perfrom operation which you want.

Answer (score 0):

The view is passed to the `DeleteCard` method, so you can get the id of the view using `view.getId()` and then you can switch the id like this:

```
 public void DeleteCard(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.buttonDelete:
        ....
        break;

        case R.id.buttonAdd:
        ...
        break;



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onClick()` from the XML, and add the click listener in the `onCreateViewHolder(..)` method. The position can be retrieved from the `getPosition()` method in the ViewHolder class which is deprecated now.

You can get the position using the `getAdapterPosition()` or `getLayoutPosition()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getPosition()

Comment: How would I add the onClick() to the onCreateViewHolder method? Sorry, I'm very new to Android.

Comment: This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395114/add-onclick-listener-to-predefined-button

Comment: How can I access the button view from the onCreate method though?