# How to set click listener on two different buttons within a list item when using cursoradapter?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am building an **attendance management** app.

The list has two different buttons to mark either **present** or **absent**. How should I add a click listener for both of the buttons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add onclick listener to predefined button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395114/add-onclick-listener-to-predefined-button)

Comment: For situations like this where there are only 2 options you should use a checkbox or a switch or a togglebutton. You don't need 2 buttons.