# XML files and the ActionBar

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android programming, migrating over from iOS and I am having a hard time.

So, I have set up a new application in Eclipse IDE with a fixed tab and swipe navigation. So it appears to have created a ActionBar. However, I need to change the content of each page rather than it just telling me which tab I clicked.

I have been searching for this for about, 30-45 mins now, and I cannot find anything which makes any sense!

How can I attach a new XML file to a view?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you are looking for is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file)
```

Make sure your xml file is in your res/layout folder in your project

As for your button listener, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320148/1031312).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, where abouts in the code would this go?

Comment: This is the java code which goes in your activity. If you want to change the view on a button click it would go into the button action method

Comment: P.S. I think you should read this doc top to bottom since you don't understand the basic structure of an android app: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I get that part, I should have been more specific sorry, do I have to add an event handler to the actionbar?

Comment: @JoshBoothe you can use a universal OnClickListener for the View and switch between actions depending on which button ID was pressed