# Mathematical formula with variables and spinner

Tags: android, math, spinner, formula

I hope someone can help me? I'm trying to solve a problem I have with getting a certain number into a formula.

I've made some Changes but I can still not get it to work. It crashes when I try to open it. Anyone know why? From the Logcat I can see that the problem is in OnCreate.

public class ActivityEnergy extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
    EditText etNum10;
    EditText etNum20;
    EditText etNum30;
    int nrjspinner = 0;
    Object value;

    Button btnNrj;

    String oper = "";

    TextView tvResult;

 ArrayList<String> nrjmethod = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.energy);

     // find the elements
    etNum10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum10);
    etNum20 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum20);
    etNum30 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum30);

        btnNrj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNrj);

        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        // set a listener
        btnNrj.setOnClickListener(this);

  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 

  // Create the ArrayAdapter
  ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this,
          R.array.nrjmethod, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                 // Set the Adapter
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


  // Set the ClickListener for Spinner
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

          value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
          switch (position) {
          case 0:
              nrjspinner = 1;
              break;

          case 1:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 2:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 3:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 4:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 5:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 6:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 7:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 8:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 9:
              nrjspinner = 0.8;
              break;

          case 10:
              nrjspinner = 0.6;
              break;

          case 11:
              nrjspinner = 0.6;
              break;
          }

      }


      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {



    } 

        });


 }

    @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                float num10 = 0;
                float num20 = 0;
                float num30 = 0;
                float result = 0;

                // check if the fields are empty
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum10.getText().toString())
                    || TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum20.getText().toString())
                    || TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum30.getText().toString())) {
                  return;
                }

                // read EditText and fill variables with numbers
                num10 = Float.parseFloat(etNum10.getText().toString());
                num20 = Float.parseFloat(etNum20.getText().toString());
                num30 = Float.parseFloat(etNum30.getText().toString());

             // defines the button that has been clicked and performs the corresponding operation
               switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnNrj:
                  oper = "";
                  result = (float) ((nrjspinner * ((num10 * num20) / num30))*0.001);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;

                }

             // form the output line
                tvResult.setText("Your result = " + result);

    }


}
```

And here's the logcat

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.develope.axson/se.develope.axson.ActivityEnergy}: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at se.develope.axson.ActivityEnergy.onCreate(ActivityEnergy.java:52)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)

10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497):     ... 11 more

Comment: Something's off here. You said b, c, and v are constants, but in the code, you are retrieving them from text in the same manner as k. What happens when you set a break point just after parsing each string to a float? What values do you have for num1, num2, num3, and num4?

Comment: constants might be the wrong word. My English isn't perfect. Sorry about that... The user types his values for b,c and v. But the K-value depends on what method he's using. Unfortunatly the user doesn't know the values himself, just the method. For example the method could be drawing with a pen and the value is how much ink you use per meter.

Comment: Can it have something with the onClickListener to do, since a have a button for making the calculation? Spinners requires OnItemSelectedListener if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I've changed the code. Please have a new look at it. Do you have any idea @A.S. and @Mark?

Comment: 10-27 17:40:58.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1497): at se.develope.axson.ActivityEnergy.onCreate(ActivityEnergy.java:52)   What's in this line

Comment: btnNrj.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging and check getting value from spinner. May be you can not get the value from spinner. In such cases, the best solution is debugging.

Comment: I've changed big parts of the code but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Finally!

First of all the biggest problem was the SetOnClickListener(THIS);
It made everything crash. I got rid of the Listener-function and replaced it with the following solution:

In the XML-file - add android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"

For example:

```
    <Button
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="@string/calcNrjbtn"
    android:textSize="8pt" 
    android:id="@+id/btnCalcNrj">
```

And in the java - Replace OnClick with your defined OnClick

For example:

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double num10 = 0;
        double num20 = 0;
        ....
```

It was Chronos who gave me that solution in the following thread: [Android OnClickListener - identify a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320115/android-onclicklistener-identify-a-button)

Since I was using decimals, INT didn't work so I changed to DOUBLE instead and everything worked.