# How to set button listenr in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write listen for button

```
button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.choose_group_button);
```

how to write lister for button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android OnClickListener - identify a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320115/android-onclicklistener-identify-a-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do your stuff             
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, either:

1. Assign an on click event to your button.

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.button_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
   });
   ```
2. - For this, in your xml file for your button view you'd set:

     ```
     android:onClick="onClick"
     ```
   - And in your class you'd have your on click method which would look like:

     ```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){
         switch(view.getId()){
             case R.id.button_id:
             // do stuff
             break;
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: FYI: First option has problems with casting, second options mixes up two other approaches. If you use the `onClick` attribute, you don't need an `OnClickListener` - just a `public void` method taking a single `View` arg. If you go with the `implements` route, just `setOnClickListener(this)`.

Comment: oh yea, was late last night ha, the 'OnClickListener' wouldn't be needed.