# get the ID of the clicked image button

Tags: android, button, onclick, nullpointerexception

I have many image buttons on my application.

Currently I use the .getID() for another method for my game. I would also like to see the Id myself.

I have tried to assign the Id to a text view within the button click like this,

```
clicker = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                ImageButton clicked = (ImageButton) v;
                makeMove(clicked.getId()); // getting the id of where the person has clicked, and calling makeMove method which is defined below

                TextView clickID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickId);
                clickID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                clickID.setText(clicked.getId());

            }

        };
```

But I get a nullpointer for the,

```
clicked.getId();
```

Is there another way to get this information?

Also am I assigning it wrong?

I'm very new to android, and don't know where to turn for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Also my log cat is,

```
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at         com.example.con4.ConnectFourActivity1$2.onClick(ConnectFourActivity1.java:178)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at         android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-12 18:23:27.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `NullPointerException` comes from the line `clicked.getId()`? What exactly is on `ConnectFourActivity1.java` line 178?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the the click.getId into method, then displayed it, so then I could view the id in logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in few ways. If you have separate listener for each button, then you know the button and can get it using `v.getId()`. If you have one listener for all, then you can use switch statements to identify which one was clicked. See [Android OnClickListener - identify a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320115/android-onclicklistener-identify-a-button) . It explains for a button but its same for ImageButton as well.