# Android 1 function for 3 buttons

Tags: android

I have 1 function to print the text of the button, and i use that function for the 3 button, how do i know in what button the user click? (sorry but my english is low)
Example:

```
        public void function(View view) {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        text.setText(button <?> .getText()); }
```

is the number of the button the user click

Its any way to know in which button the user click?
Please help, Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android OnClickListener - identify a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320115/android-onclicklistener-identify-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define one click listener and set this listener for all buttons. For example:

```
private OnClickListener genericListerner = new OnClickListener() { 
    public void Click(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
              case R.id.button3:
               text.setText(button3.getText().toString());
              break;
              case R.id.button4:
              text.setText(button4.getText().toString());
              break;
              case R.id.button5:
              text.setText(button5.getText().toString());
              break;
              default:
              //do something
    } 
};
```

and you set the listeners like the following:

```
button3.setOnClickListener(genericListener);
button4.setOnClickListener(genericListener);
button5.setOnClickListener(genericListener);
```

I am not sure whether this is what you are asking, but what this code basically does is that, if you click button 3 it sets the textview's text to button 3's text,  if you click button 4 it sets the textview's text to button 4's text and  if you click button 5, it sets the textview's text to button 5's text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TheFiddle47 i edited my answer you can see it there.

Comment: That realy help, thanks. And thanks to all the people who try help me.

Answer (score 0):

The view that is passed in is the one that was clicked, therefore it has the id.

```
view.getId() == R.id.button3
```

If you still need help, share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will require some onclick listeners for the button, you can then set an id or name in the onclick e.g

```
 final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             text.settext("Button1 Clicked")
         }
     });
```