# Relative Layout All Childs Clickable

Tags: java, android

This Question Is Pretty Silly to ask but out, but i Would like to know how it Works?

I had  a `Relative` Layout with 2 `ImageViews` as Child having separate `clickListner` instances. One above Another, of same Size and Attributes.

Overlaps Each other. Both having Different images.
Question is When i click on one image both `ImageView` Click listners are Called.

Or if i disable the Click on ImageView Top, The ImageView Below Still Works, I was Clicking on Image View Above though. How it is I'ts Getting callback from both.

I Just Want to know How it works? not The code, i do not have any issue writing code for `clickListners` Whether only one Working or Both.

```
<RelativeLayout

----
---
>
<ImageView
---
---<!--Child 1-->
<ImageView
---
---<!--Child 2-->



<RelativeLayout/>
```

Comment: And where is the **relevant** code?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320148/232727):
if you are working with just one clicklistener, you can do:

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
          // it was the first button
          break;
        case R.id.b2:
          // it was the second button
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ImageButton**

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imgButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addButtonListener();
}

public void addButtonListener() {

    imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ImageButton is working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this to your parent layout
android:context="Yourclasshere"
then give this to your image view
android:onclick="onclick"

and then implement the on click listener or make the method like Vitly A make above