# Create animation on homescreen when widget is clicked

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation, android-windowmanager

What Clean Master app does is that it put a widget on home screen and when user tap it , it cleans RAM and show an animation like this on homescreen(on top of homescreen) - [image]

and i also want to do this ....

What i have done till now is that i have created a widget on homescreen and when user taps i received it inside an **AppWidgetProvider** class . shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148103/handling-a-button-click-in-a-home-screen-widget)

I also think it shows this animation by using this feature - **WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT** , like what messenger did by overlaying chatheads on top of screen. This can be done like this - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads).

But i am still confused on what would be the best approach for doing this.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create Activities with transparent backgrounds. These activities will appear over the homescreen but will still show the homescreen behind it. When the App Widget receives a broadcast, it can create a PendingIntent to start this transparent activity, which will then be displayed over the fullscreen.

Comment: yeah it is possible but that's not how clean master do it......no activity is open when its widget is tapped