# Problem retrieve similar child element of firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve only the date and all the date element at once and store them in array in the firebase as shown below.

[image]

i have used the following code to retrieve but failed to that.

```
    public void showData(View view) {

    final ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Date");

    firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            date.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            display.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Please help to find a solution for this.

Comment: The path you are giving is not correct, you are missing 2 nodes. It should be FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Name").child(actual_name).child("Date");

Comment: the problem is not solved with this.

Comment: One way is like you have to set your reference until the "Name" node any then you have to traverse manually for the "Date".

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan do mark the answer as correct and vote it up, this helps the stack overflow readers and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @PeterHaddad in the previous answer, the sequence to access the data you have taken is not right. You may try this way, if nothing else helped until yet.

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("Names").orderByChild("Date").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        date.add(ds.getValue(String.class));
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

//Also as you've told that code is not working, please tell, what exactly is not working
```

Comment: Can you tell more, what exactly do you want to do with this? What exactly is going wrong with the code?

Comment: you have given me the correct solution i think there is some problem with the code. can you check it.

Comment: i have created the apk but when runtime it crashes.

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan do mark the answer as correct and vote it up, this helps the stack overflow readers and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

The firebase reference is wrong, you should go from the top node to the date node.

Change this:

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Date");
```

into this:

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Name");
 firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        date.add(datas.child("Date").getValue().toString());
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Since you want to get **all** `Date` then put the firebase reference at the node `Name` and loop inside the names to be able to retrieve all the dates.

---

If you want to get the date of one user example `Ravi`, then you do not need to loop, you can do the following:

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Name").child("Ravi").child("Date");

firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    date.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
       }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
 });
```

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan what's the problem? Also which way because I gave two ways to retrieve

Comment: I want the answer in the first way but it seems not working.

Comment: i want to retreve the data ie. "Date" on onclick event in my app. Can you tell me event listners for onclick event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320115/android-onclicklistener-identify-a-button