# UtteranceProgressListener not being reliably called

Tags: android, listener, text-to-speech

I am writing an `Android` app to fetch the latest email from a folder and play it using TTS.  I want to be able to use it whilst driving so it has to be mostly automatic.  Everything so far is working fine until I attempt to capture when the `TextToSpeech` has finished speaking so we can move on to the next email.

Here is the complete `MainActivity.java` file:

```
package uk.co.letsdelight.emailreader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

public TextToSpeech tts;
private Bundle ttsParam = new Bundle();
public UtteranceProgressListener utListener;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
private Properties imap = new Properties();
private String textToSpeak = "";

@Override
public void onInit(int ttsStatus) {
    if (ttsStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        utListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("started reading (Listener)");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done Event Listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("finished reading (Listener)");
                /*ImageButton i = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);*/
                isPlaying = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop(String s, boolean b) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Event Listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("stopped reading (Listener)");
                /*ImageButton i = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);*/
                isPlaying = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Event Listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("Error reading email");
                ImageButton i = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
        };
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(utListener);
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("initialised");
    } else {
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("failed to initialise");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    imap.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    imap.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "143");
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void restartPressed(View v) {
    if (isPlaying) {
        tts.stop();
        speak();
    }
}

public void playPressed(View v) {
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) v;
    if (isPlaying) {
        isPlaying = false;
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("");
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
        }
    } else {
        isPlaying = true;
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_stop);
        new Reader().execute();
    }
}

class Reader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("fetching email");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String toRead = "nothing to fetch";
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(imap, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(getText(R.string.hostname).toString(), getText(R.string.username).toString(), getText(R.string.password).toString());
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX.Articles.listen");
            if (inbox.exists() && inbox.getMessageCount() > 0) {
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount() - 6);
                if (msg.getContentType().contains("multipart")) {
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(multiPart.getCount() - 1);
                    toRead = part.getContent().toString();
                } else {
                    toRead = msg.getContent().toString();
                }
            } else {
                toRead = "The folder is empty or doesn't exist";
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            toRead = "Error fetching email - " + ex.toString();
        }
        return toRead;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        String body;
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("");
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
            body = doc.body().text();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            body = "Error parsing email - " + ex.toString();
        }
        status.setText("email successfully fetched");
        textToSpeak = body;
        if (isPlaying) {
            speak();
        }
    }
}

private void speak() {
    int maxLength = TextToSpeech.getMaxSpeechInputLength();
    if (textToSpeak.length() > maxLength) {
        textToSpeak = "The email text is too long! The maximum length is " + maxLength + " characters";
    }
    ttsParam.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "EmailReader");
    tts.speak(textToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ttsParam, "EmailReader");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

The inner class `Reader` works fine.  `doInBackground` fetches the email and `onPostExec` strips out any HTML to leave the actual text content of the email.  This is passed to the `speak()` method which does the actual speaking and works.

The issue is with the `onUtteranceProgressListener`.

Sometimes the `onStart(String s)` method is called, sometimes it isn't!  It seems to never be called the first time the email read out.  Mostly it is called for subsequent calls to `speak()` but not always.  About 1 in 5 times it fails to get called.  If the listener is called the status displays 'started reading (Listener)' otherwise it shows 'email successfully fetched'.

`onDone`, `onError` and `onStop` are never called.

I have tried using different `utteranceID` and `Bundle` values in the `tts.speak()` call but this makes to difference.

When the app is started, the first status display is 'initialised' which means that the `onUtteranceListener` must have been set within the `onInit` method.  The `TextToSpeech` object is instantiated within the activity's `onCreate` method.

I have looked through all the information I can find which has mostly suggested getting the `utteranceID` correct.  What else can I try in order to get a better understanding of this problem please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the onDone() method (and in fact any of the progress callbacks) is run on a background thread, and therefore the Toast is not going to work, and any code that accesses your UI such as setText(...) may or may not work.

So... the methods probably *are* being called, but you just can't see that.

The solution to this would be to surround the code in your callbacks with runOnUiThread() like this:

```
@Override
public void onDone(String s) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done Event Listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
            status.setText("finished reading (Listener)");
            /*ImageButton i = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);*/
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    });

}
```

Note: It's probably best to initialize your TextView in onCreate() along with everything else instead of in the progress callbacks.

Also, the purpose of the utteranceID is to give each call to speak() a unique identifier that is then passed back to you as the "String s" argument in the progress callbacks.

It's a good idea to give each call to speak a new ("most recent") ID using some kind of random number generator, and then checking it in the progress callbacks.

You can see a similar question and answer regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233235/setonutteranceprogresslistener-not-at-all-working-for-text-to-speech-for-api-2/52266610#52266610).

Side note:

Since you have a "restart" button, you should know that on APIs <23, calls to TextToSpeech.stop() will cause the onDone() in your progress listener to be called.  On APIs 23+, it calls onStop() instead.

Comment: Thank you, that has certainly moved me forward.
Although a slight change to your code is required.  The listener needs to be within the run() method of runnable():

Can you suggest why the onStart() listener worked sometimes and not other times?

Comment: The app is being built for API 26 as my mobile runs Android 8.0 and it is not intended for general distribution.  Although I have specified a minimum API 23 in the IDE because I am testing on an Android 7.0 device.

Comment: Oh OOPS! Sorry about that... fixed it.  With regards to onStart() (or any of the callbacks), my theory is the same -- that it *appeared* to only work sometimes because background calls to the UI thread sometimes DO work... but mostly don't... but always do work if you use runOnUiThread(...).

Comment: Will the same technique of wrapping the code within `runOnUiThread` work within the `doInBackground` method of `Reader`?  I need to keep a handle to the email message so that it can be deleted or moved once the content has been read out by TTS

Comment: I'm not sure...  There should be a better way of accomplishing that.  I would recommend asking a new question about that.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you actually have a problem and not a race between who sets the text in what order. Use log statements to make sure it is not actually called.

Try setting queueMode to QUEUE_ADD like:

```
tts.speak(textToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParam, "EmailReader");
```

maybe subsequent calls are cancelling the listener's events from previous texts inputs, as QUEUE_FLUSH suggests.

Also the bundle isn't really needed there, you can set it to null.

Hope any of these helps.

Comment: Thanks - if the `Bundle` isn't needed here, when would it be needed?