# TTS not impacted by the volume set by the AudioManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-to-speech, android-audiomanager

I am having an issue with implementing my TTS (Text To Speech) application. Basically, I am trying to override the current volume with max volume when I trigger my Text To Speech method. I can see the changes in the volume control on the phone but it does not seem to effect the volume for the TTS as the TTS volume remains the same. I can't figure out the exact problem.

**3 methods which I call in sequence**

```
setMaxVolume();
activateTTS(myString);
setDefaultVolume();
```

**setMaxVolume**

```
private void setMaxVolume(){
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
}
```

**activateTTS**

```
private void activateTTS(String myString) {

    if(androidAPILevel < 21){
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, "1");
        textToSpeech.speak(myString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
    } else{
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putFloat(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 1f);
        textToSpeech.speak(myString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, null);
    }

}
```

**setDefaultVolume**

```
private void setDefaultVolume(){
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolume, 0);
}
```

The purpose is to give the volume control to the user and not allow the TTS service to be impacted by the phone volume.

Additional functions to assist the solution:

```
private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
private int androidAPILevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
AudioManager audioManager;
int currentVolume;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,
            this
    );

    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) {
            if (!getUserPreference().getTest()) {
                Toast.makeText(TimeWhisperService.this, "TTS Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setDefaultVolume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) {

        }
    });

    Log.v(TAG, "oncreate_service");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(Float.parseFloat(getUserPreference().getSpeed() + "f"));
    textToSpeech.setPitch(Float.parseFloat(getUserPreference().getPitch() + "f"));


    if(getUserPreference().getTest()) {
        activateTTS(getMyString());
    }
    else{
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setMaxVolume();
                activateTTS(getMyString());
                //setDefaultVolume();
            }
        }, 0, getUserPreference().getTimer() * 10000);
        Log.v(TAG, "onstart_service");
    }
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Log.v(TAG, "oninit");
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
            result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Language is not available.");
        } else {
            //textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
            activateTTS(getMyString());
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Could not initialize TextToSpeech.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're "calling in sequence" your three methods, but what actually happens is that the third method is called, resetting the system volume back to normal... before the TTS even begins speaking.

The reason is, as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech), the speak() method is asynchronous.

So... the way to resolve this is to create an UtteranceProgressListener and to move the setDefaultVolume() method into its onDone() method.

Side-note: In order for any of the UtteranceProgressListener callbacks to be called, the utteranceID cannot be null... so that is changed also:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int androidAPILevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    int currentVolume;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                start();
            }
        });

        textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {
                Log.i("XXX", "onDone() called.");
                setDefaultVolume(); // sets volume back to normal *after* speech is done.
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                Log.i("XXX", "onError() called.");
                setDefaultVolume(); // sets volume back to normal *after* speech is done.
            }
        });
    }

    private void start() {
        setMaxVolume();
        activateTTS("hello! hello! hello! hello! hello! hello!");
    }

    private void activateTTS(String myString) {

        if(androidAPILevel < 21){
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, "1");
            params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "thisNeedsToBeSet");
            textToSpeech.speak(myString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
        } else{
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putFloat(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 1f);
            textToSpeech.speak(myString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, "thisNeedsToBeSet");
        }

    }

    private void setMaxVolume(){
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    }

    private void setDefaultVolume(){
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolume, 0);
    }

}
```

EDIT: It's a good idea to implement your desired behavior in BOTH onError() and onDone() callbacks.  One or the other of these is always called as far as I understand.  This way, if there is an error, your volume won't get stuck in the high position.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. What you are saying makes sense and I'll keep you updated

Comment: Hi Boober, I've implemented the code as you've suggested. Clearly it's not the exact same code as your but I am not sure in terms of how to adapt the code. Basically, the TTS is a service so I am not sure if that makes a difference. Can you please have a look at the code again. I've tried to debug it and noticed "onDone" function isn't even triggered.

Comment: Is the volume behaving correctly?  The reason that you don't think onDone() is being called could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465605/utteranceprogresslistener-not-being-reliably-called/52475431#52475431

Comment: Well, the volume functions are behaving correctly but onDone is not working correctly which I will need to use to set the default volume.

Comment: +1 for great answer as I didn't set the params as you've indicated in the activateTTS method. Works like a charm! Thanks a lot mate, you clearly deserve the bounty and good explanation.