# program is skipping to on Start method without running text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

```
  t1.speak("Hi sir", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
  onStart();
```

> Blockquote
>   speak is not running and it directly skips to the on Start method but it run if i remove on start method .I want to go to the on start method once it complete speaking hi sir.

Answer (score 0):

The speak method is asynchronous, and spawns a *new thread* that runs simultaneously to the code already running, so that's why execution does not "pause" and it simply continues to the next line.

You will have to have t1.speak() be the last instruction in whatever method contains it, and before calling speak, set an [UtteranceProgressListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener) on your t1... and override the onDone() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onDone(String s) { // this method is called from a background thread...

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // ... so this is important :)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onStart(); // <-------- move your onStart here.
        }
    });

}
```

Here is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233235/setonutteranceprogresslistener-not-at-all-working-for-text-to-speech-for-api-2/52266610) that you can use for complete details on how to set an UtteranceProgressListener.