# How to make sure TextToSpeech is initialized before using speak?

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

I'd like to ask you for some help with Android `TextToSpeech` feature.
Basically, I'd like to develop a simple AI which speaks, asking a question then waits for an answer, and at last, based on answer asks another question and so on, until user pronounces a keyword which stops everything.

Now I know `TextToSpeech` has to be initialized before using `speak` method, and I'm trying to take this into account by using `onActivityResult` method.

Below some code:

Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnInitListener, Button.OnClickListener{
    Button sayHello;
    TextView textView;
    private static final int CHECK_DATA = 0;
    private static final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.UK;   // British English
    private static final String TAG = "TTS";
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    private boolean isInit = false;
```

sayIt Method: used to speak:

```
public void sayIt(String text, boolean flushQ){
        if(isInit){
            if(flushQ){
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            } else {
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TTS instance not properly initialized");
        }
    }
```

TextToSpeech Listener:

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status){
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            isInit = true;

            // Enable input text field and speak button now that we are initialized
            sayHello.setEnabled(true);

            // Set to a language locale after checking availability
            Log.i(TAG, "available="+tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK));
            tts.setLanguage(defaultLocale);
            // Examples of voice controls.  Set to defaults of 1.0.
            tts.setPitch(1.0F);
            tts.setSpeechRate(1.0F);
            // Issue a greeting and instructions in the default language
            tts.speak("Initialized!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, Integer.toString(12));
        } else {
            isInit = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TTS instance not properly initialized");
        }
    }
```

Button Listener:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(isInit)
            sayIt("You clicked!", true);
    }
```

onActivityResult Method:

```
// Create the TTS instance if TextToSpeech language data are installed on device.  If not
    // installed, attempt to install it on the device.
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CHECK_DATA) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

                // Success, so create the TTS instance.  But can't use it to speak until
                // the onInit(status) callback defined below runs, indicating initialization.

                Log.i(TAG, "Success, let's talk");
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this,  this);

                // Use static Locales method to list available locales on device
                Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
                Log.i(TAG,"Locales Available on Device:");
                for(int i=0; i<locales.length; i++){
                    String temp = "Locale "+i+": "+locales[i]+" Language="
                            +locales[i].getDisplayLanguage();
                    if(locales[i].getDisplayCountry() != "") {
                        temp += " Country="+locales[i].getDisplayCountry();
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, temp);
                }

            } else {
                // missing data, so install it on the device
                Log.i(TAG, "Missing Data; Install it");
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

And, at last, `onCreate` Method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sayHello = findViewById(R.id.sayBtn);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        sayHello.setEnabled(false);
        sayHello.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_DATA);
        /* THIS SPEAK DOES NOT WORK! */
        sayIt("Speech from method!", true);
    }
```

Issue is: `Button` successfully gets enabled when `onInit` method initialises `TextToSpeech` and successfully pronounces text. 
My goal is to make the `Activity` `speak` from `onCreate` method, since at the moment it only works from `onInit` and `onClick` listeners, bot not in `onCreate`, even if I check for `tts` initialization using `onActivityResult`.

Basically I want the `TextToSpeech` to speak with no `Buttons` involved.

I know very similar questions were already posted, but none solved my problem. Have some idea?
Hope I've been clear, Thank you!

**UPDATE:** Log shows ERROR detected occurs in `else` branch of `onInit` method, where `Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TTS instance not properly initialized");` line is.

Comment: It seems that TTS requires some time to init. So if you call it straight from `onCreate()` it is still not initialized. You may experiment to call it with some delay using method described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android

Comment: You have to wait until `onInit()` is run with the `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` status. You already have the `isInit` variable, so use that to check. And if you want to speak something as soon as possible then trigger it from `onInit()`.

Comment: Already tried using boolean value in order to check initialization, did not worked. @bvk256 suggestion worked perfectly though. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SabrinaAldrovandi please note that timeout time may be different on each device, so proper testing is required

Comment: @bvk256 Yes, I'm developing this app in order to use it on a limited amount of devices, so I'll test this on each one and see how to arrange timeout time.

Comment: Why don't you just make a method myOnCreate() and call that from inside onInit() ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233235/setonutteranceprogresslistener-not-at-all-working-for-text-to-speech-for-api-2/52266610#52266610

Comment: Adding a delay seems pretty desperate and brittle - I was hoping for a more solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** 
The only thing to do here is to wait a little time in order to let `TextToSpeech` initialize for good. 
A good way seems to be by using a delayed `Handler` as follows:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Waiting for RobotTextToSpeech initialization for 1500ms
                rtts.speak("This speak will work!");
                rtts.speak("This other speak will work too!");
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
```

By doing this, looks like `TextToSpeech` works well even in `onCreate` method, we just have to wait little time.
Hope this can help.