# UtteranceProgressListener works overall but the events onStart and onDone don't work

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Here's the SpeechSynthesizer.java file containing the overridden onDone and onStart

```
package ru.cadmean.speechforunityjava;

import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

public class SpeechSynthesizer {

    private boolean isReady;

    private String currentLanguage = "en-US";
    private float currentRate = 1f;

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public SpeechSynthesizer(Context context, SpeechSynthesizerDelegate delegate) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(context, status -> {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("Speech", "Failed to initialize text to speech: " + status);
                return;
            }

            tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            tts.setSpeechRate(currentRate);

            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    delegate.onSpeakingStarted();
                    Log.d("Bruh", "speaking started2");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    delegate.onSpeakingFinished();
                    Log.d("Bruh", "speaking finished2");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    delegate.onSpeakingCancelled();
                    Log.d("Bruh", "speaking Cancelled2");

                }
            });

            isReady = true;
        });
    }

    public boolean isReady() {
        return isReady;
    }

    public void speakText(String text, String lang, float rate) {
        if (!currentLanguage.equals(lang)) {
            currentLanguage = lang;
            tts.setLanguage(new Locale(lang));
        }
        if (currentRate != rate) {
            currentRate = rate;
            tts.setSpeechRate(rate);
        }
        Log.d("Speech", "Speaking: " + text);
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    public boolean isSpeaking() {
        return tts.isSpeaking();
    }

    public void stopSpeaking() {
        Log.d("Speech", "Stopping");
        tts.stop();
    }
}
```

And here's the main file where out subscribed delegates should work but don't.

```
package ru.cadmean.speechforunityapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import ru.cadmean.speechforunityjava.SpeechSynthesizer;
import ru.cadmean.speechforunityjava.SpeechSynthesizerDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editSpeechText;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;

    private SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(getApplicationContext(), new SpeechSynthesizerDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void onSpeakingStarted() {
                Log.d("Bruh", "speaking started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpeakingFinished() {
                Log.d("Bruh", "speaking finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpeakingCancelled() {
                Log.d("Bruh", "speaking cancelled");
            }
        });

        editSpeechText = findViewById(R.id.editSpeechText);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!speechSynthesizer.isReady()) {
                Log.d("Bruh", "Not ready");
                return;
            }

            speechSynthesizer.speakText(editSpeechText.getText().toString(), "ru-RU", 1f);
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking();
        });
    }
}
```

[I also made the repository public](https://github.com/cadmean-ru/SpeechForUnityApp)

The overall problem is that when I press start the app speaks but the event onDone or onStart doesn't trigger.

Comment: Curious if my answer worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that when you call speak, you're setting the parameters (specifically, the utteranceID) as null.

So, in SpeechSynthesizer.speakText(), add the following:

```
// set params
// *** this method will work for devices API 19+ ***

String mostRecentUtteranceID = "blahblahblah";
   
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, mostRecentUtteranceID);

tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
```

The "blahblah" is just a quick workaround so that you can see the problem.

If you want to differentiate between utterances, then use a unique id for each speak call. (see [setOnUtteranceProgressListener not at all working for Text To Speech for API > 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233235/setonutteranceprogresslistener-not-at-all-working-for-text-to-speech-for-api-2/52266610#52266610))